# Fill youtube comment field with Imacros

Tags: youtube, comments, imacros

When i want to fill the youtube comment field, my macro doesn't do anything. It's interesting, if i want to extract the content, it works fine.

NOT working (fill):

```
''FRAME F=n try with 2-5, changes at refresh
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TABINDEX:0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ROLE:TEXTBOX CONTENT=something
```

Working (extract) (write something in the box ofc) :

```
''FRAME F=n try with 2-5, changes at refresh
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TABINDEX:0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ROLE:TEXTBOX EXTRACT=TXT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use experimental recording and command EVENT.